# how to match and replace multiple route parameter using angular replace function

Tags: javascript, angular

I'm trying to replace multiple parameter using angular replace function but the problem that the function detected the first parameter.

eg: I have this route `admin/management/{type}/card/{id}`, the route.replace function result `admin/management/waiting/%7Bid%7D` it work fine with the first parameter.

```js
/**
 * @param route 
 * @param obj 
 * @returns 
 */
  getFormattedRouter(route: String, obj: any) {
    console.log(route);//admin/management/{type}/card/{id}
    return route.replace(/{([a-zA-Z_]+?)}/, function (match, capture) {
      console.log(match);//{type}
      console.log(capture);//waiting
      //detected the first one then stops
      return obj[capture];
      //admin/management/waiting/%7Bid%7D
    });
  }
```

how can I detect all the parameters in a route.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your regexp does not seem to be capturing all the matches, you can try this instead `/({\w*})/g`. Note also the `g` at the end that indicates the fact that you want to find all the matches, not stop after the first one. Check [this link](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_regexp_g.asp) for more info.